# How to add a index in Tabulator with Vuex?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, tabulator

I use Tabulator with Nuxtjs
Everything works fine but when I want to add an **index**, I have the error

[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

Here is the code

```
  watch: {
    tableData:{
      handler: function (newData) {
        this.tabulator.replaceData(newData);
      },
      deep: true,
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
      index: 'p',
      data: this.data,
      layout: "fitData",
      columns: [ 
        {title:"Num", field:"p"},
        {title:"pn", field:"pn"},
        {title:"par", field:"par"},
        {title:"typec", field:"typec"},
        {title:"ch", field:"ch"},
        {title:"ar", field:"ar"}, 
      ],
      rowClick:function(e, row){
        $nuxt._router.push({ path: '/C/' + row.getIndex() })
      },

    });
    // test to upade row
    this.tabulator.updateData([{p:1, pn:"test"}, {p:3, prixnom:"test"}]);
  }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found
it is necessary to add

```
created () {
    this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rt));
  },
```